# Issues with ApplicationCommands between modules in Wpf with Prism

Tags: wpf, button, command, prism, menuitem

I am using WPF with Prism. 
I have a Custom Canavs **DrawingCanvas.cs** in **Module A** where i have set **ApplicationCommands.Delete** as commandbinding as follows.

`this.CommandBindings.Add(newCommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Delete, Delete_Executed, Delete_Enabled));`

I have another **Module B** where i have a **MenuItem** delete, and another **Button** for delete. I have set command from **xaml** for both as follows.

`<MenuItem Header="Delete" x:Name="menuItemDelete" Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"`

```
<Button x:Name="buttonDelete" Background="Black"   Height="25" Width="25" ToolTip="Delete" Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"/>
```

Here **MenuItem** for Delete works fine as expected.(**MenuItem will be enabled when some drawing is selected in DrawingCanvas from UI and "Delete_Executed" in DrawingCanvas.cs will be called when on Delete menu item click**)

But Delete button is always **Disabled**. It doesn't get enabled when some drawing is selected in DrawingCanvas from UI.
I am wondering why the same command working for MenuItem but not for Button in same view and same Module.

Can anybody help me with this? Am i doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a button would need commandtarget. Having said that I almost never work the way you're doing this. Since this is UI dependent I'd probably use a static command and check what has focus or whatever the logical criteria should be. Maybe you should consider that if you don't want your button enabled ALL the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the CanExecute for the ApplicationCommands.Delete returns false all the time. There is one way to solve this - through the Window's command bindings:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The event handler would look like:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

It can always be true if you want it to be enabled all the time or just add your condition as in when you want it enabled.

Comment: You're welcome, do mark as answered if this has solved your problem.

Comment: where shall i add above event handler and command binding? Actually i already have this event handler in DrawingCanvas.cs . But it does not get called for Button,but its getting called for MenuItem in the same view. I am not understanding why this is happening.

Comment: Just have one common event handler for the Window or the UserControl that has the Menu as well as the button.

Comment: Actually in my scenario as i explained in the question both event handler(CanExecute,Execute) are in **DrawingCanvas.cs** in **Module A** and Menu Item and button are in same UserControl inside **Module B**. So for MenuItem both CanExecute and Executed are getting called in **DrawingCanvas.cs**. but for Button both are not getting called. Any idea why?